# How to convert this recursive Java method to iterative? (CodeJam challenge)

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, recursion, iteration

I'm trying to adapt this [solution](https://github.com/salvois/codejam/blob/master/src/codejam2017/finals/DiceStraight.java) to the Code Jam's [Dice Straight](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6314486/dashboard#s=p0) problem to Python. Unfortunately, it requires too deep recursion to work correctly in Python (unless both recursion limit and stack size are significantly increased). So I'm trying to convert this recursive [method](https://github.com/salvois/codejam/blob/master/src/codejam2017/finals/DiceStraight.java#L136) to iterative:

```
/**
 * Attempt to recursively free a die by selecting a different die for the same value.
 * @return true if the die has been freed, false if no other die can be found.
 */
boolean freeByShuffling(Die die) {
    assert die.valueUsing != null;
    // First check if we can just use another dice for the previous value
    for (Die otherDie : die.valueUsing.dice) {
        if (otherDie.valueUsing == null) {
            otherDie.valueUsing = die.valueUsing;
            die.valueUsing = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Nope, we must free a die recursively
    diceVisitedWhileShuffling.add(die);
    for (Die otherDie : die.valueUsing.dice) {
        if (diceVisitedWhileShuffling.contains(otherDie)) continue;
        if (freeByShuffling(otherDie)) {
            otherDie.valueUsing = die.valueUsing;
            die.valueUsing = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is my Python code which doesn't quite work, although it solves most test cases:

```
def free_by_shuffling(self, die):
    assert die.current_value is not None

    stack = [(None, die)]
    found = False

    while stack:
        this_die, other_die = stack.pop()
        self.visited.add(other_die)

        if found:
            other_die.current_value = this_die.current_value
            this_die.current_value = None
            continue

        for next_die in other_die.current_value.dice:
            if next_die in self.visited:
                continue
            if next_die.current_value is None:
                found = True
                stack.append((other_die, next_die))
                break
        else:
            for next_die in other_die.current_value.dice:
                if next_die in self.visited:
                    continue
                stack.append((other_die, next_die))

    return found
```

How do I convert the original method to use iteration instead of recursion?

Comment: In what way does your solution "not quite work"?

Comment: @Chris: answers for a small number of test cases are wrong with the iterative function (off by `1` or `2`), while with the recursive one all answers are correct.

Comment: I changed some things around in your solution and now only 4 test cases are incorrect.  I'll keep trying to see if I can get it.

Comment: I'm confused by the upvotes on this question. Doesn't it clearly violate "Questions _seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")_ must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"? "Doesn't quite work" and "a small number of test cases are off by 1 or 2" (especially without detail) aren't clear problem statements. The OP has been here for a long time; surely they know this isn't a good question?

Comment: @Chris: read the title again. I don't seek debugging help.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash, your title may not ask for debugging help but I think the body of the question does. (If we're just looking at the title, isn't it dangerously close to code translation?)

Comment: @Chris The Python code shows what I've tried before posting the question. An answer may or may not use it, apparently.

Comment: I'm down to 3 incorrect test cases (two are off by 1 and one is off by 2).  I'm skeptical that I'll be able to do any better, though.

Comment: @Jacob G: After some trial and error I've come up with a correct solution. The key was to correctly emulate the recursive calls with a stack :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Python implementation works well for both 'small' and 'large' input files:

```
def free_by_shuffling(self, die):
    assert die.current_value is not None

    stack = [die]
    found = False

    while stack:
        this_die = stack.pop()

        if found:
            if stack:
                this_die.current_value = stack[-1].current_value
                stack[-1].current_value = None
            continue

        for other_die in this_die.current_value.dice:
            if other_die.current_value is None:
                stack.extend((this_die, other_die))
                found = True
                break
        else:
            self.visited.add(this_die)

            for other_die in this_die.current_value.dice:
                if other_die not in self.visited:
                    stack.extend((this_die, other_die))
                    break
            else:
                if stack:
                    for other_die in stack[-1].current_value.dice:
                        if other_die not in self.visited:
                            stack.append(other_die)
                            break
    return found
```

Any comments and suggestions are welcome.